# MOXy @XmlPath sub element text

Tags: java, moxy

I'm using MOXy for marshaling objects to xml.
I'm trying to have two properties mapped as sub-elements each with a second discriminator element (not attribute) like this:

```
<person>
    <name>
        <type>First</type>
        <value>John</value>
    </name>
    <name>
        <type>Last</type>
        <value>Smith</value>
    </name>
</person>
```

My class was mapped like this:

```
    @XmlRootElement
    public class Person {
        @XmlPath("name[type/text()='First']/value/text()")
        private String fistName;
        @XmlPath("name[type/text()='Last']/value/text()")
        private String lastName;
    }
```

And I get the following error:

```
Exception [EclipseLink-25016] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.XMLMarshalException
Exception Description: A namespace for the prefix type/ns0:text() was not found in the namespace resolver.
```

I also tried adding namespaces to the xpath and the exception wasn't thrown, however the type element wasn't present in the xml.

Usually when I want to do this with attributes instead of elements, I map:

```
@XmlPath("name[@type='First']/value/text()")
private String fistName;
@XmlPath("name[@type='Last']/value/text()")
private String lastName;
```

And it works flawlessly, is there a way to get the result I'm expecting with a simple xpath?

Answer (score 0):

In your xml, you have two elements with "First", can you try with First and Last?

Comment: Sorry, that was a mistake in the question. The intention was to have First and Last as you say, I edited the question.